# Error in using MapViewOfFile function for creating vector<int> data

Tags: c++

I need to create a `vector< int >` data in program1 and use that in program2 using `CreateFileMapping`:

Here is the code of the program1:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){ 
HANDLE hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,NULL,PAGE_READWRITE,1,L"MyFileMappingObject");

HANDLE hBuffer = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);

vector<int>*  pBuf = (vector<int>*)hBuffer;

for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
pBuf->push_back(i);


_getch();//wating for pressing any key
UnmapViewOfFile(hBuffer);
CloseHandle(hMapFile);

Return 0;
}
```

And the code of the program2 is:

```
//headers…
int main(){

HANDLE  hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, L"MyFileMappingObject");
HANDLE  hBuffer = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);

vector<int>*  pBuf = (vector<int>*)hBuffer;

for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
  cout << pBuf->at(i) << endl;
//pBuf->push_back(i);


UnmapViewOfFile(hBuffer);
CloseHandle(hMapFile);

Return 0;
}
```

When I run the program1 I can add item to the vector but in the program2 I can’t read and add and modify items. In the program2, I see “**Unable to read memory**” for each item of the vector in debugging;
What is wrong and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see where you actually allocated enough memory for a `vector<int>`, and you haven't mapped the data memory it creates dynamically. Right?

Comment: Yes , and i add items by push_back method

Comment: You did not address my comment. It sounds like you do not understand how a vector works. Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/13973021/560648

Comment: vector<int>*  pBuf = (vector<int>*)hBuffer;

Comment: What do you think that line of code does?

Comment: I saw this link before but my problem not solved

Comment: Then read and study the text found on that page. It explains pretty much everything.

Comment: The address of memory hBuffer convert to vector<int> type

Comment: I used another type such as double , int instead of vector<int> and it worked correctly.

Comment: Is the problem in the CreateFileMapping function size of memory allocation?

Comment: std::vector stores its data in memory that allocates using its allocator type argument.  The default one you use in your code uses the heap, not your memory mapped file.  You also never constructed the vector object.  The MMF isn't going to accommodate the dynamic sizing that std::vector requires.  So sure, this can't go anywhere.  Golden Rule with MMFs is to keep your types as simple as possible, you need int* here.

Comment: The problem is what I said it was 7 hours ago.